# String replacement with array index

Tags: c#, .net, string, int

```
for (int i = 0; i < NumberOfRFIDTransponders; i++)
{                 
  if (ReadDataFromReader == "ReaderLeft")
  {
    for (int j = 0; j < NodeIDList.Count; j++)
    {                         
       NodeIDList[j] = NodeIDList[j].Replace("LeftReader.DATABASE_UPDATE[0]",
       "RightReader.DATABASE_UPDATE[" + Convert.ToString(i) + "]");                                                    
    }
  }
}
```

The following is happening: I'm replacing the index of my DATABASE_UPDATE array with the index `i` of my first for loop. I also replace the name of my reader. The output of every loop within the loop with index `j` is that the name of the reader is replaced correctly but every index is set as `[0]`. So, the `Convert.ToString(i)` isnt working.

Comment: Won't this only work the first time through the outer loop?  Once you replace the `NodeIDList` values, your replaces won't do anything the 2nd time since the string has already been replaced.

Comment: @David Thank you sir!